# Power Bi Can't create relationship between tables even relationship is possible

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization

I've these four tables "Central, east, west and south"  and I want to build relationship but, I was not to able build. I'm getting error what does it mean? Can anyone tell me how to resolve it? Even I clicked on "Autodetect" Relationships then it says - "There are no relationships found" Please help. But, relationship is possible after doing drag and drop I got an error. [Clearly we can see that the relationship is possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfGyY.png)
[This error show what does it many how can overcome with this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvOPJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you are not using data relationships in Power BI as they are intended to be used. It's tough to say without seeing your data, but I would guess you actually want to append your central, east, west, and south tables into one table in power query editor. You can also add an additional column to track which table or superstore each row originally comes from.

Here are some resources to help

[Star Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema)

[Append Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries)

[Add a Custom Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/add-custom-column)

Comment: share you email I will send on your email.